# Javascript save same ID without overwritting the other one in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm making a parking application for my school. The problem is when I save sir X with ID '123-ABC' and then comes miss Y and has same ID '123-ABC', it removes X and Replaces with Y.

Here's my code:

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function ()
{
  var user = document.getElementById("user").value;

  var gegevens = { 
    naam:  document.getElementById("naam").value, 
    voornaam: document.getElementById("voornaam").value, 
    aankomsttijd:valueTijd, 
    telefoonnummer: document.getElementById("telefoonnummer").value
  };

  localStorage.setItem(user, JSON.stringify(gegevens));       
}, false);
```

Comment: You should save array of objects...`[{}, {}, {},....]`

Comment: Why did you tag this as java ?

Answer (score 0):

Rayon Dabre is right you can do like this

You can save users as array:

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function() {

var users = localStorage.setItem(users);
if (users) {
        users = JSON.parse(users);
    } else {
        users = [];
    }
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var gegevens = {
        naam: document.getElementById("naam").value,
        voornaam: document.getElementById("voornaam").value,
        aankomsttijd: valueTijd,
        telefoonnummer: document.getElementById("telefoonnummer").value
    };
    users.push(gegevens);
    localStorage.setItem(user, JSON.stringify(users));
}, false);
```